# Can dotless query string override existing variables?

Tags: asp.net, less, dotless

Inside ASP.net I'm serving a dynamic less stylesheet with dotless. I'm using a query string to pass in the variables.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/style.less?&color1={{var1}}&color2={{var2}}>
```

The variables are already declared in LESS (color1: red, color2: blue), I would like to override these values if they are passed in the query string. This does not work right now because dotless actually *prepends* the variables from the query string, and less uses the *last* declared variable.

I see two options, but I don't how to achieve these:

1. Append the variables instead of prepend them. This is how dotless does the prepending: https://github.com/dotless/dotless/blob/master/src/dotless.Core/Engine/ParameterDecorator.cs
2. Set the less variables color1 and color2 as optional - only if they're not set before. Something like:

   ```
   color1: color1 || red;
   ```

   Does something like this exist in LESS (/dotless)?

Answer (score 0):

Less do not have the option to set default values for variables, see http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-default-variables for the reason that you don't need them, already mentioned by you the last declaration wins (and Less uses Lazy Loading).

But on  https://github.com/dotless/dotless/wiki/Parameters i found:

> -v --disable-variable-redefines - Makes variables behave more like less.js, so the last variable definition is used

Setting this option to `false` should fix your issue:

```
<dotless disableVariableRedefines="false" />
```